# How do I SELECT data from more than one table and display it, with PHP ?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a Private Message Application. And I need the Inbox to show both "main messages" and "answers on messages".

My tables are as listed:

**post**

id - header - content - from_user - to_user - receiver_opened - user_bywho - timestamp.

**post_answer**

id - answer_from_user - answer_to_user - answer_user_bywho - answer_header - answer_content - answer_id - timestamp_svar.

And now I'm having troubles. Because I don't know how to make this possible.

My mysql_query looks like this right now:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];    

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post,post_answer WHERE ".
                  "answer_to_user='$user' AND to_user='$user'")
       or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to present them? A flat list of everything ordered only by timestamp, and not keeping posts and their responses together? A two-level tree with answers shown under the posts they go with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is not valid as it will be ambiguous about the `id` field.

### USE JOIN

To do this, you can either use `JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
    FROM post 
    INNER JOIN post_answer
    WHERE post.to_user = post_answer.answer_to_user
```

### THE STUPID WAY (easy to understand)

```
SELECT post.id, 
       header, 
       content, 
       from_user, 
       to_user, 
       receiver_opened, 
       user_bywho, timestamp,
       post_content.id, 
       answer_from_user, 
       answer_to_user, 
       answer_user_bywho, 
       answer_header, 
       answer_content, 
       answer_id, 
       timestamp_svar
    FROM post, 
         post_content
    WHERE answer_to_user=$user AND 
          to_user=$user
```

Hope this helps

### UPDATE

Lets suppose your table contains fields like-

1. firstname
2. lastname
3. number

See if you get the result in an array say `$results`.

```
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->firstname;
    echo $result->lastname;
    echo $result->number;
}
```

Comment: Hi Aniket. This looks like the other. And I think what I'm having trouble with. Is how to echo the data out.

Comment: @Kolind With the second query, you will need to manually write down all the field names for getting the values from your table, and then, from the record set, get them individually using `foreach()`

Comment: Hey.. I know I've given you the answer green. But I have a problem: Now it only selects if there's both a post and a post_answer. How do I make it pick everything from post and post_answer with the to_user='$user'?

Comment: @Kolind Are the id of post and post_content related??

Comment: post_answer... No, they have their own ID's.

Comment: @Aniket let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2539/discussion-between-kolind-and-aniket)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at joins:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: I've been looking at joins before. But it's like nothing works for me.

Comment: "Nothing works" isn't enough information for us to help you. Describe what you've tried, what the results were, and why you don't think those results were what you wanted.

Comment: Remember, different types of joins do different things

Comment: @Joe White I've tried the INNER JOIN below. Which gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM POST INNER JOIN POST_ANSWER WHERE
    POST.TO_USER = POST_ANSWER.ANSWER_TO_USER
```

Comment: If you're using INNER JOIN, it would be more idiomatic to use ON instead of WHERE -- keeps the join conditions together with the join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                     FROM post p, post_answer pa 
                     WHERE ".
                        "pa.answer_to_user='$user' AND p.to_user='$user'")
       or die(mysql_error());
```

You give aliases to your tables and use the aliases to specify which table contains which column in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I have to ask you something then. When I'm using JOIN how do I print it out with a while loop then, like if it was information from only 1 table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to put those into one query, or at least not the query you're providing there.

This query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post,post_answer WHERE answer_to_user='$user' AND to_user='$user'
```

Will result in one row with far too many columns:

```
id - header - content - from_user - to_user - receiver_opened - 
user_bywho - timestamp  - answer_from_user - answer_to_user - 
answer_user_bywho - answer_header - answer_content - answer_id - timestamp_svar
```

This query will provide all of the posts which meet all of your requirements.

```sql
-- look for all posts to the user
SELECT * FROM POST WHERE to_user = '$user'
UNION DISTINCT
-- look for all posts where an answer exists which is to the user.
SELECT * FROM POST P WHERE EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 FROM post_answer PA WHERE P.ID = PA.ID AND 
      answer_to_user = '$user' );
```

You should then look for the POST_ANSWERS in a separate query -- these are separate piece of data, realistically you shouldn't get them from the same request.