# How to display data from two data table in one table

Tags: php

I have two tables, `image` and `video`. I want to display all data from image and video in one table. I know how to display all data from video but how to display all data from image also in same table. There is table where I display all data from video but can someone please tell me how to display all data from images in same table when displaying data from video is finished.

```
<table width="879" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="11" align="center" ><strong>All uploaded videos</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="51" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Id</strong></td>
    <td width="95" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Video</strong></td>
    <td width="83" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="130" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td width="177" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Description</strong></td>
    <td width="101" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Price</strong></td>
    <td width="174" align="center" bgcolor="#000000" class="yellow"><strong>Added by</strong></td>
  </tr>

  <?php $path= "videoFile/";
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
  ?>

  <tr>  
    <td>
      <?php if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { echo $rows['vid'];}else { echo "For admins only!"; }  ?>
    </td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $path.$rows['filename'] ?>">View video</a></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['alttext']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['imagedate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$".$rows['price']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['user_nicename']; ?></td>    
  </tr>

  <?php
    }
  ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: $sql1="SELECT * FROM video join wp_users on video.userID=wp_users.id order by imagedate ";

$sql2="SELECT * FROM images join wp_users on images.userID=wp_users.id order by imagedate ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM video 
JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.id = video.userID
JOIN images ON images.userID = wp_users.id
ORDER BY imagedate
```

*Check for the admitted answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079595/how-do-i-select-data-from-more-than-one-table-and-display-it-with-php?rq=1).*